# Referencing label from Select clause in where, simple sql query

Tags: mysql

Consider I'm having a query such as:

`SELECT student.name, MAX(grades.final_grade) as max_grade
From grades , students
where student.id == grade.student_id and max_grade == 90`

Is this query wrong and won't work, because it's illegal to acess label mentioned in select in a where clause?

Answer (score 1):

"Aggregates" cannot be referenced in `WHERE`.  But they can be moved to `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  student.name, MAX(grades.final_grade) as max_grade
    From  grades , students
    where  student.id = grade.student_id
    HAVING  max_grade = 90
```

Also it is `=`, not `==`.